# Jenkins Pipeline Get Rejecter Name instead of user id

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have followed below link to reject /approve deployment request. But if i reject deployment i can only get user id. How can i get user name?

**def user = err.getCauses()[0].getUser()**

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226554067-Pipeline-How-to-add-an-input-step-with-timeout-that-continues-if-timeout-is-reached-using-a-default-value?mobile_site=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to this as below

def user = err.getCauses()[0].getUser().getDisplayName()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    import hudson.model.Cause
    import hudson.tasks.Mailer
    import hudson.model.User

    def name = cause.getUserName()
    println "name is ${name}"
    def jenkins_id = cause.getUserId()
    println "jenkins_id is ${jenkins_id}"
    User u = User.get(jenkins_id)
    def umail = u.getProperty(Mailer.UserProperty.class)
    def email = umail.getAddress()
    println "email is ${email}"
```

You may want to read the JavaDocs of the `User` class to see if the name is available.

Comment: No luck i get below error                                                                                                                              hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Class.getUserName() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: Apparently `cause` in your case is an empty array and not an instance of `Cause`.

Comment: What do you suggest?